# how to add bootstrap to my website to html code

Tags: html, responsive

I made my website and now I want to make it responsive by adding bootstrap, how can I add it to an existing html? I know it should have classes but how can I make it

thanks alot

Comment: Bootstrap use a grid system. You can start from [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) to get start with bootstrap, and [This link](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/) to understand the grid system

Comment: I downloaded the bootstrap file and added it to my html, but from searching what I understood is I have to divide my page into cols that fit each device, and I am not sure where to put my content

Comment: thank u so much will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link into `<head>` tag to add bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: go to bootstrap website [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: it will show you the classes and its effects on tag

Comment: If that helped you, mark this answer with the green tick!